# Maximum and minimum number of nodes in a suffix tree

Tags: algorithm, suffix-tree

What are the maximum and minimum number of nodes in a suffix tree? And how can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for posting. Please include some code to show [what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865639/maximum-and-minimum-number-of-edges-in-a-suffix-tree

Comment: That are edges, I want to know it for nodes.
There is nothing to implement, I just have to know how many nodes there can be in a suffix tree.

Comment: "What are the maximum and minimum number of edges in a suffix tree? And how can I prove it?". You are asking for edges not nodes in your question text, in the title you are asking for nodes..

Comment: Just wanted to plug http://cs.stackexchange.com because I think it is even more suited there.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat That's right. To OP: Do let me know if you move the question there. I'd like to move the answer as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming an input text of `N` characters in length, the minimum number of nodes, including the root node and all leaf nodes, is `N+1`, the maximum number of nodes, including the root and leaves, is `2N-1`.

**Proof of minimum:** There must be at least one leaf node for every suffix, and there are `N` suffixes. There need not be any inner nodes, example: if the text is a sequence of unique symbols, `abc$`, there are no branches, hence no inner nodes in the resulting suffix tree:

[image]

Hence the minimum is `N` leaves, `0` inner nodes, and `1` root node, in sum `N+1` nodes.

**Proof of maximum:** The number of leaf nodes can never be larger than `N`, because a leaf node is where a suffix ends, and you can't have more than `N` distinct suffixes in a string of length `N`. (In fact, you always have exactly `N` distinct suffixes, hence `N` leaf nodes exactly.) The root node is always exactly `1`, so the question is what is the maximum number of inner nodes. Every inner node introduces a branch in the tree (because inner nodes of a suffix tree have at least 2 children). Each new branch must eventually lead to at least one extra leaf node, so if you have `K` inner nodes, there must be at least `K+1` leaf nodes, and the presence of the root node requires at least one additional leaf (unless the tree is empty). But the number of leaf nodes is bounded by `N`, so the maximum number of inner nodes is bounded by `N-2`. This yields exactly `N` leaves, `1` root, and a maximum of `N-2` inner nodes, `2N-1` in total.

To see that this is not only a theoretical upper bound, but some suffix trees actually reach this maximum, consider as an example a string with just one repeated character: 'aaa$'. Confirm that the suffix tree for this has 7 nodes (including root and leaves):

[image]

**Summary:** As evident, the only real variable is the number of inner nodes; the number of roots and leaves is constant at `1` and `N` for all suffix trees, while the number of inner nodes varies between `0` and `N-2`.

Comment: RE: "Proof of maximum"
Thanks, simple explanation, which looks correct.