# Finding out whether there exist two identical substrings one next to another

Tags: string, algorithm, hash, substring

We've got a String.

ABAEABABEABE

Now we've got to check whether there exist a substring that is followed next by another substring that's exactly the same as the first one.

In this example:
ABAEAB**ABE**ABE

ABE is followed by ABE and that are two identical substrings.

In this example:
AAB
It would be simply A, beacuse A is followed by another A.
In this example:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
There doesn't exist such a substring, so the answer would be NO.

I only managed to find an algorithm that would run in O(n^2). That is getting Hashes and its prefixes. Then for each letter we expand simply and check all the words ending on that letter. There are n letters. We need to expand it n times. So it's O(n^2). I believe there should be a O(n log n) algorithm for this problem.

Does anybody have a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want the longest substring possible that follows this pattern.

The first thing to do is to build a Suffix tree of the input string. Using [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf), this is *O(n)*.

Now, how does the condition you provided translate in the suffix tree? First things first, you are looking for a *repeated substring* **<sup>[1]</sup>**. *Repeated substrings* will appear as internal nodes of the suffix tree. [The maximum number of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389858/maximum-and-minimum-number-of-nodes-in-a-suffix-tree) in a suffix tree built from a *n*-char string is *2n - 1*.

You can build a Max-Heap containing such repeated substrings, using their length (number of chars). **You do *NOT* keep substrings of length superior to *N/2* (see [1])**. This is *O(N)* where *N* is the number of internal nodes of the suffix tree. For any suffix tree:

> 0 ≤ *N* ≤ *n - 2*

Now, you take the max out of the priority queue and process the internal node *i* you obtained:

1. Let *S<sub>i</sub>* be the substring related to *i*, *k* = 0 and *curnode* = *i*
2. While *k* < length(*S<sub>i</sub>*)

   1. If the key from *i* to a child of *i* is equal to *S<sub>i</sub>[k]*, then *k = k+1*
   2. Else break the loop.
3. If *k* == length(*S<sub>i</sub>*), then the substring is a match. Else, you proceed to the next substring.

### Complexity summary

Let *n* be the length of the query string.

- Building the suffix tree : *O(n)*
- Building the Max-heap of repeated substrings: **[3]**

  - Identifying the repeated substrings (ie. internal nodes) and storing them in an array: *O(n)*
  - Heapify the array: *O(n)*
- Finding the best match: *O(n².log(n))* **<sup>[2]</sup>**

Hence the overall worst case complexity is the sum of the above and is *O(n².log(n))*.

### Notes

I made the algorithm above... Hence it is suboptimal, if you are brave enough, you can go through [this paper](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~gusfield/lineartime.pdf) that describes a linear time algorithm! In any case, *Suffix trees* are a key to this problem so I suggest you study them thoroughly.

**[1]**: Warning, repeated substrings may partially overlap!

**[2]**: Actually, the worst case complexity is better than this very naive upper bound but I don't know how to prove it (yet?!). For example, if there were *n - 2* internal nodes, that would mean that the original string consists of *n* occurrences of the same character. In that case, the first substring we check is a match => it's O(n.log(n)).

**[3]**: If we replace the heap construction by a regular sort (*O(n.log(n))*), the final comparison step runs in *O(n²)* instead of *O(n².log(n))* ... Taking down the overall complexity between *O(n.log(n))* (due to the sorting step)  and *O(n²)*.

Comment: I think that time complexity is wrong.  You need O(length(S_i)) to check whether the first heap entry i represents a tandem repeat (since it might be that the second copy of S_i appears elsewhere in the string, and the string that follows S_i matches it only for the first length(S_i)/2 characters).  So you then need to pop the next entry from the heap, and try it.  You might need to repeat this length(S_i)/2-1 times.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You're right, K.log(n) is the lower bound (where K is the length of the longest repeated substring (<= n/2)). Nonetheless it seems that the real complexity is still lower than the naive worst scenario (checking all repeated substrings in the heap => O(n².log(n)))

Comment: I see you've edited, but there are still a couple of references to the original time bound in your answer.  I agree that it's better than the O(n^3) brute force approach, but interestingly it's not as good as just running the Z algorithm (e.g. http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107) starting at each position in turn, which will take O(n^2) and doesn't need a suffix tree.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That must come from the fact I use the suffix tree in a very suboptimal way. I may not be translating the substring properties we require well enough. Anyway even though the lower bound is n.log(n)) and the upper bound O(n².log(n)), I think it's far better than this naive upper bound

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved with 'divide and conquer' Main-Lorentz algorithm:
Michael Main, Richard J. Lorentz. An O (n log n) Algorithm for Finding All Repetitions in a String [1982]

**Edit**: [algorithm description and C++ implementation in Russian](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/string_tandems) (might be translated with Chrome browser)

There exists also [linear-time algorithm](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/articles/mfcs2003.pdf) (don't know about practical implementations)

Comment: Longest common prefix does not guarantee it will be one after the other.

Comment: Also - finding all repetitions in a string does not guarantee "one after the other", and I am skeptic about `O(nlogn)`  time, since there are O(n^2) repetitions in "aaaaaaaa....aa", it must be dependent on the size of the output as well - and that might be an overkill to find **all** reprtitions in this case.

Comment: @amit OK, removed that variant

Comment: @amit 'Crochemore triplets' allow to code all tandem repetitions with nlogn such triplets (using repetition counts)

Comment: Ok, but if you have only the count - and not the repetitions themselves - how would you find out if they appear one after the other? I am not saying it cannot be done nor this is not the right direction - but the solution as is, is lacking details.